Which parent class defines function being overriden by override keyword?
I am using a third party library with this class hierarchy:
A <- B <-C
I write my own class D as a subclass of C, and I want to override function foo() that is defined in some class of the parent hierarchy:
class D : public C {

  void foo() override;
}

Assuming documentation for the parent hierarchy is lousy - Is there some way to know which class of the parent hierarchy also defines foo()?
Thanks!

Either your IDE may be able to display that information, or you can look at the header files for A, B, and C.  Note that class D : C is private inheritance, so D is not an A, B or C.

Are you asking if there is some code you can write to figure that out or for some tool to parse your code base and figure it out?

The information is in the header files. You only have to look. And any decent IDE will be able to tell you the class hierarchy with all member definitions.

Also, it is possible that none of the parents define the member function. Consider for example a pure virtual member function.

@user17732522 a pure virtual method would still be declared in one of the parent classes. Also, a pure virtual can also have a definition in the original declaring class, but that's not common. Being "pure" just means it MUST be overrriden, but it can have a default implementation that descendants can call.

Now I'm curious about which library this is :-)

@Eljay - oops I forgot 'public' on the inheritance in my example code.
My subclass uses the 'override' keyword for the function and I have the doxygen pages for the inheritance - for the life of me am unable to find the method declaration anywhere.

Is foo an actual name? If not, the actual name might be stomping upon some reserved names of compiler, used internally, then behaviour is unpredictable. e.g. use names like _Foo or __foo, or __Foo is technically UB. Method declaration also can be generated by mixture of template and macroses, Qt Framework is a good example of that, or have variable-like declaration, e.g. "FuncType foo;whereusing FuncType = void(void);` Most open-source IDE's struggle with laterone, it's like the possibility was forgotten.

one ocould thin that using dual inheritance and forcing ambiguity may force compiler to complain and tell which class is source of ambiguity. But that wouldn't always work if hierarchy used virtual inheritance.

This should not matter. The public API is clearly that C contains the virtual void foo() method. How C gets that function is not part of the API, and you shouldn't rely on that. That's not "lousy documentation", that's "undocumented implementation detail which might change in a future version".

Here are two ways in one example that cause the compiler to tell you in the error messages which function is overridden:
struct A {
    virtual int foo(int);
};

struct B : A {
};

struct C : B {
    char foo(int) override {
    // ^^^ error: incorrect return value
    // overridden function is listed
        return B::foo();
        // ^^^ error: incorrect arguments for base class version
        // candidates are listed
    }
};

And these are the errors:
<source>:9:10: error: conflicting return type specified for 'virtual char C::foo(int)'
    9 |     char foo(int) override {
      |          ^~~
<source>:2:17: note: overridden function is 'virtual int A::foo(int)'
    2 |     virtual int foo(int);
      |                 ^~~
<source>: In member function 'virtual char C::foo(int)':
<source>:12:22: error: no matching function for call to 'C::foo()'
   12 |         return B::foo();
      |                ~~~~~~^~
<source>:2:17: note: candidate: 'virtual int A::foo(int)'
    2 |     virtual int foo(int);
      |                 ^~~
<source>:2:17: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided


If what you want is to check at compile time whether a derived class overrides its parent's method or not and you know the names of the classes and the method, you can use the following concept:
template <typename Base, typename Derived>
concept override_foo =
    std::is_same_v<decltype(&Base::foo), decltype(&Derived::foo)> == false;

Demo

This will not work if foo is overloaded though.
